# Multi-Cam Module Error

Tags: camera, raspicam

I am trying to run 2 Camera Modules via the Multi-Cam Module([https://www.amazon.com/Arducam-Camera-Adapter-Compatible-Raspberry/dp/B012UQWOOQ](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B012UQWOOQ)) on a Ras-Pi 2B. The pi is running the latest version of Raspibian Jessie(`Linux raspberrypi 4.4.11-v7+ #888 SMP`,) and I've been sure to enable cameras with the configuration tool. However, when trying to run [this](http://www.arducam.com/multi-camera-adapter-module-raspberry-pi/) demo code after setting up, I am getting the following output (appears 4 times, one for each call to a camera):

```
mmal: Cannot read camera info, keeping the defaults for OV5647
mmal: mmal_vc_component_create: failed to create component 'vc.ril.camera' (1:ENOMEM)
mmal: mmal_component_create_core: could not create component'vc.ril.camera' (1)
mmal: Failed to create camera component
mmal: main: Failed to create camera component
mmal: Camera is not detected. Please check carefully the camera module is installed correctly
```

The error persists when I try to access only one camera at a time, and I am quite sure that I did indeed install the module correctly. The error also persists across the singular Camera modules. What is causing this error, and what can I do to be able to capture images from the cameras?

Answer (score 2):

You need to either run `raspi-config` and enable the camera that way, then reboot, or else add to `/boot/config.txt` (then reboot):

```
start_x=1
gpu_mem=256
```

Which is all `raspi-config` does -- actually it sets `gpu_mem` to 128, which is (apparently, I haven't tried less) the minimum required for the camera to work.  So two cameras, maybe twice the memory...this is deducted from your "CPU mem", BTW, i.e., that's about actual RAM allocation, so on a quad-core model you will have 3/4 GB left.

The (poorly or un- documented) `start_x` enables the camera.

Comment: Tried this, and unfortunately no dice. I checked out the config file after enabling through raspi-config  and the two lines you mentioned were indeed there. Output of the program remains the same :(